# Какие есть грамотные способы ручного или полуавтоматического управления значением версии проекта в git-репозитории?

Tags: php, git, версионность

Много написано о версионировании в целом, но нигде не нашёл о ручном управлении значением версии проекта в *git*-репозитории.

Для примера, сейчас пробую такую последовательность действий, храня версию в файле `VERSION` в корне проекта:

1. При создании репозитория создаю файл `VERSION` и пишу туда `0.0.0-dev`. Все коммиты до выпуска следующей версии помечены этой.
2. Когда версия готова и пришла пора сливать `dev` в `master`, делаю слияние с `--no-commit`, во время которого меняю версию на `0.1.0`.
   Сейчас в `dev` осталась `0.0.0-dev`, а в `master` уже `0.1.0`.
3. Возвращаюсь в `dev`, меняю версию на `0.1.0-dev` и делаю коммит.
4. ...

Меня смущает костыльность коммита в `dev` ради номера версии.

**Какие есть грамотные способы ручного или полуавтоматического управления значением версии проекта в *git*-репозитории?**

---

### Дополнения

1. Значение версии должно быть доступно программе вне репозитория. Например, версия выводится в консоли при работе программы.
2. Допускаю, что сам вопрос про ручное управление значением версии может быть не грамотным, тогда не стоит на него жёстко ориентироваться и можете просто поделиться своим действующим опытом.

Comment: [`git tag 0.0.1`](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/Основы-Git-Работа-с-метками)  не подходит?

Comment: по последней ремарке вопрос - в каком языке вы работаете? это ключевое т.к. во многих современных языках это уже встроенно в экосистему (Rust/Python/Go)

Comment: Применительно к этому случаю — PHP.

Comment: «Меня смущает костыльность коммита в dev ради номера версии» — это же изменение файла, а значит коммита никак не избежать.